# pymongo error: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping

Tags: python, pymongo-3.x

I think the query is correct but still an error.

```
    findQ = {"fromid": wordid}, {"toid":1}        
    res= self.db.wordhidden.find(findQ)
```

However, find_one(findQ) works. So I can't find the wrong thing.
I use python 3.6 and pymongo.
Here is my code:

```
 def getallhiddenids(self,wordids,urlids):
  l1={}
  for wordid in wordids:
    findQ = {"fromid": wordid}, {"toid":1}
    res= self.db.wordhidden.find(findQ)
    for row in res: l1[row[0]]=1
  for urlid in urlids:
    findQ = {"toid": urlid}, {"fromid":1}
    res= self.db.hiddenurl.find(findQ)
```

This is an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\green\Desktop\example.py", line 9, in <module>
    neuralnet.trainquery([online], possible, notspam)
  File "C:\Users\green\Desktop\nn.py", line 177, in trainquery
    self.setupnetwork(wordids,urlids)
  File "C:\Users\green\Desktop\nn.py", line 105, in setupnetwork
    self.hiddenids=self.getallhiddenids(wordids,urlids)
  File "C:\Users\green\Desktop\nn.py", line 93, in getallhiddenids
    res= self.db.wordhidden.find(findQ)
  File "C:\Users\green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1279, in find
    return Cursor(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 128, in __init__
    validate_is_mapping("filter", spec)
  File "C:\Users\green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\pymongo\common.py", line 400, in validate_is_mapping
    "collections.Mapping" % (option,))
TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type 
that inherits from collections.Mapping
```

Comment: I know very little about pymongo. That being said, findQ is a tuple. Can you pass a tuple to the find() method?

Answer (score 3):

> find_one(findQ) works

The error is because [PyMongo find()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) requires a dictionary or a [bson.son](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/son.html) object. What you have passed in is a Python tuple object is the form of `({"fromid": wordid}, {"toid":1})`. You could correct this by invoking the `find()` method as below:

```
db.wordhidden.find({"fromid": wordid}, {"toid": 1})
```

Technically your invocation of [find_one()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) does not work either. It just that the parameter filter has been altered by `find_one()`. see [find_one() L1006-1008](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/v3.3/pymongo/collection.py#L1006-L1008). Which basically format your tuple filter into :

```
{'_id': ({"fromid": wordid}, {"toid":1}) }
```

The above would (should) not returned any matches in your collection.

Alternative to what you're doing, you could store the filter parameter into two variables, for example:

```
filterQ = {"fromid": wordid}
projectionQ = {"toid": 1}
cursor = db.wordhidden.find(filterQ, projectionQ)
```