# I get this error TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping

Tags: python, mongodb, python-collections

I am retrieving last saved data to a text field so the user can continue what they were working on earlier, this command works fine in mongo console, in PyCharm I can't figure out the right way to write the find() query

I tried storing filter parameters in 2 separate variables as suggested here [pymongo error: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406225/pymongo-error-filter-must-be-an-instance-of-dict-bson-son-son-or-other-type-t)

```
Database.initialize()
db_data = Database.find(collection = 'notes_temp', 
                         query = ({"priority" : self.priority}, {'td': 1, '_id':0}))
        for task in db_data:
            self.t.insert('insert linestart', task)
```

database module

```
class Database:
    URI = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
    DATABASE = None

    @staticmethod
    def initialize():
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(Database.URI)
        Database.DATABASE = client['notes']
    @staticmethod
    def find(collection, query):
        return Database.DATABASE[collection].find(query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your query is defined as :

```
({"priority" : self.priority}, {'td': 1, '_id':0}))
```

so when your function gets it as input its parsed as:

```
return Database.DATABASE[collection].find(({"priority" : self.priority}, {'td': 1, '_id':0})))
```

Basically theres an extra pair of parentheses that should be removed.

A mock up solution: (obviously there are several ways you can deal with this issue)

```
Database.initialize()
db_data = Database.find(collection = 'notes_temp', 
                         query = {"priority" : self.priority}, projection = {'td': 1, '_id':0})
        for task in db_data:
            self.t.insert('insert linestart', task)

class Database:
    URI = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
    DATABASE = None

    @staticmethod
    def initialize():
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(Database.URI)
        Database.DATABASE = client['notes']
    @staticmethod
    def find(collection, query, projection):
        return Database.DATABASE[collection].find(query, projection)
```